# free an entire linked list and fill again later in ansi c

Tags: c, linked-list

Im writing a program that translates a file, and for each translation made it creates a node in a linked list and later prints those linked lists to an output file,
the program can take few files from command line, so between the file swaps I need to reset the linked.
this is the struct that I need to free:

```
typedef struct symbol{
char symName[32];
unsigned int address;
unsigned int external:1;
unsigned int entry:1;
unsigned int unknown:1;
unsigned int line_num;
struct symbol *next;
}symbol;
```

I used this code for reseting (all the nodes are malloc allocated):

```
void freeLists(symbol *sym_h){

symbol *sym_temp;

while(sym_h != NULL)
{
    sym_temp=sym_h;
    sym_h = sym_h->next;
    free(sym_temp);
}}
```

this is the list before reseting(the format is "memory address of pointer","counter","temp->adress","temp->symName"):

```
x7ff24c405790 0 0 fn1
0x7ff24c4057d0 1 100 MAIN
0x7ff24c405830 2 102 LIST
0x7ff24c405890 3 104 fn1
```

but right after the free function if I try to print the list this is the output I get:

```
x7ff24c405790 0 0 
0x7ff24c4057d0 1 100 MAIN
0x7ff24c405830 2 102 ??$?
0x7ff24c405890 3 104 ??$?
```

it seems that free only resets the symName string...
I have 2 questions basically:

1. shouldn't free remove the entire struct? or at least delete all it content?
   2.how come that after free was used I can't still travers the linked list?
2. if I delete the this function entirely, and just set the linked list head to be NULL the program runs fine, if I use the free function I get segmantation fault how doest that happen?

I will add more code snippets if needed. thank a lot!

Answer (score 0):

What is `sym_h`? You passed `sym_head` so use it:

```c
void freeLists(symbol *sym_head){
    symbol *sym_temp;

    while(sym_head != NULL)
    //    ^^^^^^^^
    {
        sym_temp=sym_head;
        sym_head = sym_head->next;
        free(sym_temp);
    }
}
```

`free` deallocates memory for a single node, so you can't use your list after `freeLists` is called. If you remove this function and just set list's head to `NULL` you won't deallocate allocated memory and that a memory leak.

Comment: sym_h is the head of the linked list(I have few that are filling along each file), function now is void freeLists(symbol *sym_h),  I've edited the main question too

Comment: the main problem i have is that after this function actualy runs i can still use the list only symName seems to go crazy, but the rest stays.

Comment: @Vilaaaaaa you should not dereference pointer after it was freed. Data may remain the same (may also change), but doing it causes undefined behavior.